# Where is the Hasagat Haraavad on Internet?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, rambam, mishneh-torah

Rambam Shabbat 4.1-2 about the Din of Hatmana.

The Rishonim cite an Hasaga of the Raavad, but it's not in the Sifre Rambam.
I found it [here](https://www.bmgasaf.org.il/adm/uplaod/file1-414.pdf)

> ראב"ד
> א"א מעולם לא נראו ולא נשמעו תהפוכות כאלה מבעוד יום אסור בין השמשות מותר, ובגמ' (שבת
> לד) סתם קדרות בין השמשות רותחות הן והוא אומר כבר נחו. ואמת הרב ז"ל כך כתב הגירסא
> אבל הפירוש שלו מקולקל ביותר, וכך הוא הפי' לזאת הגירסא, בדבר המוסיף גזרו ואפי' מבעוד יום
> גזירה שמא ירתיח פי' כיון דאטמין בדבר המוסיף גלי דעתיה דרותח קא בעי ליה לאורתא וזמנין
> דפסיק רתחיה משום דאריך זמניה ומרתח ליה משחשיכה, אי הכי בין השמשות נמי ליתסר בדבר
> שאינו מוסיף דכיון דשהה מלהטמין מחזי דרותח קא בעי ליה לאורתא, אמר ליה סתם קדרות
> המטומנות בין השמשות רותחות הן לאורתא ולא תפסוק רתיחתן, כך ראוי לפרש הגרסא אלא שיש
> לנו גרסא אחרת מיושרת.‏

But I don't know where is the source. That's the first time I see Rishonim quoting Raavad on Rambam that is not transcripted in standard editions. I searched in Hasagot Haraavad on the Rif in Sefaria and did'nt find it.

Has someone a reference, where is this Hagaa?

Edit:

I found it later in the Fraenkel edition of the Rambam. Is there a free internet source for such Hagaot? They say that the Hagaot were augmented by manuscripts, but it's not a scientific edition and the reference for this stuff is not inside the book.

There is a [manuscript online](https://www.nli.org.il/he/discover/manuscripts/hebrew-manuscripts/itempage?vid=MANUSCRIPTS&docId=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS990032549960205171) from the National Library of Israel, but it doesn't contain Sefer Zemanim

Afterwards I found a [website of manuscripts](https://www.nli.org.il/en/discover/manuscripts/hebrew-manuscripts/viewerpage?vid=MANUSCRIPTS&docid=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS990000707340205171-1) but it's almost impossible to upload

Comment: I think it's a case of copyist error that accidentally missed a hasagah, but it was preserved in other sources.

Comment: I found it in Rambam Frenkel

Comment: They just put it back in. There's probably a footnote there about that.

Comment: @N.T. no, there's no

Comment: It loads fine for me. Does [this](https://www.nli.org.il/en/discover/manuscripts/hebrew-manuscripts/itempage?vid=MANUSCRIPTS&docId=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS990000707340205171) viewer work better for you?

Comment: Did you check הגהות וציונים on the side?

Comment: I checked ילקוט שינויי נוסחאות as they recommend in the introduction. Note that I have the old Frenkel edition תשל''ה I know there is a new edition of sefer zemanim @N.T.